# What is the reason of error in my Mysql create procedure

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I can't understand what is the problem of my query in `Mysql`.
I will write my query here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_DATA (
                IN prCode INT,
                IN prName VARCHAR(250),
                IN prAuthor varchar(250),
                IN prCategory varchar(250),
                IN prMaterial varchar(250),
                IN prPrice varchar(7),
                IN prDescription varchar(1000),
                IN prComment varchar(500))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `product`(`CODE`,`NAME`,`AUTHOR`, `CATEGORY`, `MATERIAL`, `PRICE`, `DESCRIPTION`, `COMMENT`) 
    VALUES (`prCode`
            ,`prName`
            ,`prAuthor`
            ,`prCategory`
            ,`prMaterial`
            ,`prPrice`
            ,`prDescription`
            ,`prComment`)
```

It gaves me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19

[Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aJML.jpg) the structure of the Table.

Comment: The reason for the error is right there; **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19"**.

Comment: ok, but i cant understand where is the problem. i think i am using good query.

Comment: Is this your whole procedure? It ends abruptly.

Comment: Try `prCode` instead of `\`prCode\`` etc etc etc Backticks are not valid on values

Comment: it has not worked.

Comment: I have tryed for all but it still not works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the standard delimiter from ';' to another. The reason for that is because we want to pass the stored procedure to the server as a whole rather than let MySQL interpret each statement at a time.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_DATA (
                IN prCode INT,
                IN prName VARCHAR(250),
                IN prAuthor varchar(250),
                IN prCategory varchar(250),
                IN prMaterial varchar(250),
                IN prPrice varchar(7),
                IN prDescription varchar(1000),
                IN prComment varchar(500))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO `product`(`CODE`,`NAME`,`AUTHOR`, `CATEGORY`, `MATERIAL`, `PRICE`, `DESCRIPTION`, `COMMENT`) 
    VALUES (`prCode` ,`prName`,`prAuthor`,`prCategory` ,`prMaterial`,`prPrice`,`prDescription`,`prComment`);

END//
```

Comment: Updated the reason.